# How to force php strtotime to return today date if date variable is empty?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a js calendar in an HTML page and I'm passing the picked date into a PHP file. Currently, the date field is mandatory and it will display the default 1970/01/01 if no date is picked in the calendar.

I'm trying to change the behavior so that when no date is picked, then the current date will be passed into the PHP file.

The code in the PHP file is the one below:

```
$mydate = strtotime($_POST['mydate']);
$mydate = date("Y/m/d",$mydate);
```

How can I change it in order to display the current date if there's no value passed from `$_POST['mydate']`?

*PS: I'm a newbie to PHP functions and searching for similar cases in the forums did not help.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get that is because strtotime returns false if it can't parse the date.
False is typecasted to `0`, and date of `0` is 1970.

What you can do is to check if the strtotime return is false. (Not the same as isset or 0 in my opinion).

```
$mydate = strtotime($_POST['mydate']);
if($mydate === false){ // === is strict comparison
    $mydate = date("Y/m/d");
}else{
    $mydate = date("Y/m/d",$mydate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if( empty( $_POST['mydate'])){
  $mydate = date("Y/m/d");
} elseif( FALSE !== $tm = strtotime( $_POST['mydate'])) {
  $mydate = date("Y/m/d", $tm);
} else {
  $mydate = date("Y/m/d");
}
```